# Listening for/to animationend on a specific node/element in an Angular2 Component template

Tags: typescript, angular, css-animations, angular2-components

I have a problem... I have a Angular2 component in my app and this has a template like so (I have simplified this)...

```
<div [ngClass]="{'animate__left': applyTransitionClass}">
    <div>Sometimes we need to animate the whole thing...</div>

    <div [ngClass]="{'animate__more__left': applyPartialTransitionClass}">
        I am the child, sometimes I just want to amimate me and not the parent
    </div>
</div>
```

In my component I have the following TypeScript code:

```
public applyTransitionClass: boolean = false;
public applyPartialTransitionClass: boolean = false;
public childAnimationListener: Function;
public wholeAnimationListener: Function;

constructor(private animationService:AnimationService, private renderer:Renderer, private elementRef:ElementRef) {

    // here I determine whether to use .. 'transitionend', 'oTransitionEnd','transitionend', 'webkitTransitionEnd'
    this.transitionEvent = this.animationService.whichTransitionEvent();

    this.animationService.doSomething.subscribe(resp => {
        // this activates / inits the ngClass on the whole template
        this.applyTransitionClass = true;
    });

    this.animationService.doSomethingElse.subscribe(resp => {
        // this activates / inits the ngClass on the child ONLY
        this.applyPartialTransitionClass = true;
    });
}

ngOnInit(): void {


    this.childAnimationListener = this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement.children[0], this.transitionEvent, () => {
        console.log('We caught the right animation... now move to something else');
        // do stuff...
    });

    this.wholeAnimationListener = this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement.children[0].children[1], this.transitionEvent, () => {
        console.log('We caught the right animation... The Child... now move to something else');
        // do stuff...
    });

}
```

Now, say for instance I only want to listen for the animation event for the child div / element or the observable to trigger the child animation should run it seems both listeners are fired as the child is part of the parent... I have also noted that the output for the parent listener is executed before the listener for the child. I guess I could pass an event to the callback function to determine what had the animation applied to it but it seems to make the first part of the `renderer.listen` function rather useless. Perhaps I am doing this wrong? Any advice on how I should listen for events on specific parts of the Component template.

If all this sounds confusing please let me know and I shall reword this... thanks in advance